# Splitting an array w/ rxjs and resubscribe when is completed

Tags: rxjs

I have an array, I'm splitting it into a multiples chunk with a delay for 5 millisecs, with the help of rxjs operators (scan, concatMap, repeat, map) I did this

here:

```
(data: any[]) =>
from(
    Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(data.length / 5) }, (_v, k) => k + 1)
).pipe(
    scan((_acc, curr) => curr * 5, 0),
    map((index: number) => data.slice(index - 5, index)),
    concatMap((item) => of(item).pipe(delay(5000))),
    repeatWhen(_=> interval(5000))
);
```

How do I skip (avoid) the extra 5000ms delay (delay, repeatWhen) when the Observable is completed.

If I use the repeat operator instead I'm getting the **maximum call stack size exceeded** error

Comment: Can you show what you have in input and what you want in output?

Comment: as input I have an array like this `[{name:"xxx", "lastaName":"xxxx", Id:1}, {name:"xxx", "lastaName":"xxxx", Id:2}, {name:"xxx", "lastaName":"xxxx", Id:3}, {name:"xxx", "lastaName":"xxxx", Id:4}, {name:"xxx", "lastaName":"xxxx", Id:5}, {name:"xxx", "lastaName":"xxxx", Id:6}, {name:"xxx", "lastaName":"xxxx", Id:7}, {name:"xxx", "lastaName":"xxxx", Id:8}, {name:"xxx", "lastaName":"xxxx", Id:9}, {name:"xxx", "lastaName":"xxxx", Id:10}]`, as output I want  split the array into  chuncks of 5 elements every 5 secs and resuscribe

Answer (score 0):

```
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { bufferCount, delay, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const people = new Array(100).fill({}).map((v, i) => {
  return {firstNname: 'firstName-' + i, lastName: 'lastName-'+i, id:i}
}
  )
const arraySource = from(people);

const subscribe = arraySource
.pipe(
  bufferCount(5),
  concatMap((array) => of(array).pipe(delay(5000)))
)
.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cusmt1?file=index.ts)

Comment: how could I handle the resusbscription on the source observable?

Comment: Every time you execute your function,  you create a new observable.
I have updated the stackblitz but you will not resubscribe, you will emit values on the same observable that the point.